# How to compute key hash for Facebook from deployment_cert.der file?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, sha, android-keystore

I have uploaded my app APK to google and enabled app signing key to let google sign  up my app .Now ,I need the deployment key hash requested by facebook ,I did downloaded the deployment_cert.der file used to generate fingerprints but i don't know how to compute the required Key hash by facebook.Please do not tell me how to generate key hash from key store since I already have generated the key hash for the testing purposes ,what I want know is the Key hash for the release version of my app APK which is signed by google .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image]

from SHA-1 hash in hex format (as found in Play console) you can convert it into base64 hash code

example:
    **echo `00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 | xxd -r -p | openssl base64`**

and then copy generated code to 
    facebook dev account -> your app -> Basic Steeings -> Android -> Key Hashes